# Input solo reciba hasta 8000

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Necesito que al ingresar cantidad en un input solo me deje ingresar hasta 8000 y que si pongo 8500 por ejemplo me diga que cantidad maxima es de 8000.

```
 <input type="text" id="breadth1"  maxlength="8000" class="form-control big" placeholder="Ingrese ancho total">
```

tengo este input pero no se como realizarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar tu `input` a uno como este, el *atributo* `type` debe ser `number`, y con los *atributos* `max` y `min` le das el rango que desees:

```css
input{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" max="8000" min="0" placeholder="Ingrese un número"/>
```

Ahora bien, si lo quieres validar con `jquery`, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  const min = 0;    // Valor mínimo
  const max = 8000; // Valor máximo

  // Escuchamos el evento keyup de nuestro input
  $(document).on('keyup', '#num', function(){
  
    // Obtenemos el objeto
    var self = $(this);
    
    // Obtenemos el valor actual
    var value = self.val();
    
    // Si el valor obtenido es menor a nuestro valor mínimo
    // o nuestro valor valor obtenido es mayor a nuestro valor máximo
    // Le decimos al usuario que no está dentro del rango 
    // y limpiamos nuestro campo
    if(value < min || value > max){
      console.log('El número ingresado no está dentro del rango permitido');
      self.val('');
    }
    
  })

});
```

```css
input{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="num" type="number" max="8000" min="0" placeholder="Ingrese un número"/>
```

Comment: Pero si ingreso 8500 igual lo deja ingresar o si ingreso 9000 igual lo deja ingresar

Comment: @Eduard dame un momento, estoy editando mi respuesta

Comment: @Eduard puedes revisar de nuevo mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar javascript para hacer la validación, en este caso utilicé operadores ternarios que no es mas que un if (?) else (:) para simplificar un poco más el código.

```js
$('#breadth1').on('input', function(){
     console.log($(this).val());
     ($(this).val() >= 8500) ? $('p').show() : $('p').hide()
});
```

```css
.valida{
  display:none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="breadth1"  maxlength="8000" class="form-control big" placeholder="Ingrese ancho total" pattern="([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9])"> 

<p class="valida">
  esto es mayor
</p>
```

Comment: Pues si, ya depende de las necesidades del programador.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Utilizar el atributo [`max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) de `HTML5` para los `input` tipo `number`.
- Agregar una función javascript para validar que el valor ingresado sea menor al establecido en este atributo.

Ejemplo:

```js
// Usamos event-delegation
document.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var el = e.target,
    max,
    val;
  
  if(el && el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input' && el.type.toLowerCase() === 'number') {
    val = Number(el.value);
    max = el.max != '' ? Number(el.max) : Infinity;
    console.log(val, max)
    if (!isNaN(val) && !isNaN(max) && max < val) {
      el.value = max;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" /> (Max infinito)<br/>
<input type="number" max="8000" /> (Max 8000)<br/>
<input type="number" max="5.5" /> (Max 5.5)<br/>
```

Ejemplo `jQuery`:

```js
// Usamos event-delegation
$(document).on('input', 'input[type="number"]', function() {
  var val = Number(this.value),
    max = this.max != '' ? Number(this.max) : Infinity;
  
  console.log(val, max);
  if (max < val) {
    this.value = max;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" /> (Max infinito)<br/>
<input type="number" max="8000" /> (Max 8000)<br/>
<input type="number" max="5.5" /> (Max 5.5)<br/>
```